# Josso 1.8.10 on tomcat 7 - Error while starting SSO Agent

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, josso

After installing **josso 1.8.10** on **tomcat 7**, I try to run `catalina run` command, but I get this error :

```
LifecycleException: Error starting SSO Agent : Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [josso-agent-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.josso.tc60.agent.SSOAgentValve.start(SSOAgentValve.java:216)
```

**Update :**

For the commands, under the josso console I used, to install : 
The gateway :

```
gateway install --target C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59 --platform tc70
```

The agent :

```
agent install --target C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59 --platform tc70
```

The samples :

```
agent install --target C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59 --platform tc70
```

When I'm looking on the forums I can't find any solution for this.
Any Idea ?

Comment: Could you add the commands you used to install JOSSO? You should use tomcat7 installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think that JOSSO 1.8.10 and Apache tomcat 7 are incompatible for some reason, I tried a different release from JOSSO which is 1.8.6 and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Pleaase, check all configuration is correct. It seems you are using tc6 instead of tc7 agent.

1.- Check if you have added a new parameter to JAVA_OPTS to configure the JAAS for use the one installed by JOSSO installer in your tomcat.

You can modify setenv.sh for example:

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.auth.login.config=${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/jaas.conf"
```

2.- Check if your josso-agent-config.xml is for tc7 agent, in other case

```
<s:beans xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tc70="urn:org:josso:agent:tomcat70"
     xmlns:agent="urn:org:josso:agent:core" xmlns:protocol="urn:org:josso:protocol:client"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd          urn:org:josso:agent:tomcat70 http://www.josso.org/schema/josso-tomcat70-agent.xsd          urn:org:josso:agent:core http://www.josso.org/schema/josso-agent.xsd          urn:org:josso:protocol:client http://www.josso.org/schema/josso-protocol-client.xsd">
    <tc70:agent name="josso-tomcat70-agent" sessionAccessMinInterval="1000">
```

3.- Check if the file josso-agent-config.xml is a valid XML

Comment: Thank you gavioto for your answer ! I'll check this method and bring you a feedback.

Comment: ok. please, remember to mark the answer as correct in case it works

Comment: Well I test it, but still the same error. any other propositions ?

Comment: Before posting I checked all these elements.

Comment: In your error log it show tc6 instead of tc7, but you mention you are using tomcat7

Comment: The problem seems to be on this line of code https://github.com/atricore/josso1/blob/6b629ce336cb7ad29a7faf8f516d8e4cee0dcd7a/agents/josso-tomcat60-agent/src/main/java/org/josso/tc60/agent/SSOAgentValve.java#L210 becouse class tc6 is not found in your instalation. Could you tray changning xmlns for using tc70?

Comment: Finally I finished using JOSSO 1.8.6 with tomcat 7, Thank you for your answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with tomcat6. After some debugging I fixed it by adding the next libraries to tomcat/lib directory:

- axis-1.4.jar
- axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar
- josso-protocol-client-1.8.10.jar
- josso-ws-1.8.10.jar
- wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar

Comment: Thank you gimco I'll check you solution and give you a feedback ;)